# How to onboard a GCP project into Ansible Tower for running playbooks in it?

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower

I have successfully used Ansible engine to provision GCP resources, using ansible playbooks with gcp module.

Now I am trying to do so using Ansible Tower, and I'm totally new to Ansible tower.

I am unable to understand how to create an inventory in Ansible Tower for the GCP. In tower, we can provide hosts where our yaml will run. How will I determine the host IP for GCP? Use cases:

1. I want to provision a GCP compute engine .
2. I want to provision a Bigquery dataset and tables.

What should be my host in ansible tower in both cases? Could someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `Credential` to connect to GCP as below

```
- Name: GCP Credentials
- Description: GCP Credentials
- Organization: Default
- Credential Type: Google Compute Engine
- Service Account Email Address: *This will be filled when upload json file*
- Project: *This will be filled when upload json file*
- Service Account Json File: yourfile.json
- RSA Private Key: *This will be filled when upload json file*
```

Create `Inventory` as below and save

```
- Name: GCP Inventory
- Description: GCP Inventory
- Organization: Default
```

Then, in `Sources` tab of `Inventory` click in the button of `Create a new source` with this information:

```
- Name: GCP Source
- Description: GCP Source
- Source: Google Compute Engine
- Credential: GCP Credentials
```

In `Sources` tab of `Inventory` click the option "Start sync Process" of your new source. This will update your `Hosts`. With all this you just need to execute your playbook on `localhost` with a template using this credential and inventory.

Comment: Wow, it worked like magic @Gary Lopez! Thank you. Although I had set up credentials, organization, and inventory, I was not getting how to set up hosts for GCP. This information was not available on the documentation either. So thank you!

Comment: don't worry, any other question with Ansible Tower I will gladly support you.